# Does the needle of the galvanometer point in the direction the current is flowing?

Tags: electromagnetism, instrumentation

Probably a little too simple for this site but I read different answers to this so I thought I would have the electricians weight in on this.

If this is true what law of electricity is it using to do it?

Answer (score 3):

That completely depends on the construction of your galvanometer, and how it's connected. However, as any sensible measurement device, the clamps and scale of your galvanometer will clearly be labeled so that you can connect it such a way that it does.

Comment: Bottom line: you could _make_ a galvanometer whose needle points in the direction of the current going through it.  But that would be arbitrary -- you could also make it point in the direction of electron drift (which is backwards from "conventional" current, thank you Benjamin Franklin).  But I wouldn't expect a galvanometer to be either one or the other of these -- I _would_ be disappointed in one that doesn't have the terminals and the scale clearly marked with '+' and '-' signs, though.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanometer.

Here you can see that the current flows from the <kbd>+</kbd> terminal, through the spring and then turns right to run through the anti-clockwise coil as viewed from the top.

It is very unlikely that there is a standard and the terminals could be mounted one above the other so your question couldn't be answered.

Reversing the coil winding direction or the magnetic field direction would reverse the movement.